# Resizing JFrame to fit resized JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am pretty new with JPanel and JFrame and probably not working with them the way I should. I'm trying to create Pong game and after creating JFrame and adding JPanel to it, I'm able to resize my JPanel but I don't know how to resize my JFrame to fit it. Game class extends JPanel.

main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int height = 500, width =(int) (height*1.56); //height = 500, width = 780;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.setSize(width, height);
        System.out.println(game.getHeight());
        System.out.println(game.getWidth());
        game.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println(frame.getHeight());
        System.out.println(frame.getWidth());
    }
```

output:

```
500
780
39
136
```

The output should be somthing like:

```
500
780
*above* 500
*above* 780
```

EDIT:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int height = 500, width =(int) (height*1.56); //height = 500, width = 780;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.pack();
        System.out.println(game.getHeight());
        System.out.println(game.getWidth());
        game.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        System.out.println(frame.getHeight());
        System.out.println(frame.getWidth());
    }
```

Changing the setSize to setPreferredSize and then call pack() for the JFrame fixed it all.

Comment: Call `pack()` on the JFrame after adding all components. Never set size either but instead deal with preferred size (preferredSize).

Comment: I got it, Thank you! There isn't any simple answer all over the internet and you had her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, deal with preferred sizes and make sure to call `pack()` on your JFrame **after** adding components. Also, it's better to override getPreferredSize rather than calling `setPreferredSize`. For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = 300;
    private int prefW;
    private int prefH;

    public Game(int prefW, int prefH) {
        this.prefW = prefW;
        this.prefH = prefH;
    }

    public Game() {
        this(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        int height = 500; 
        int width =(int) (height*1.56); //height = 500, width = 780;

        Game game = new Game(width, height);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Frame size: " + frame.getSize());
        System.out.println("game size: " + game.getSize());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```